# unable to merge text files and collect a particular line from the text files

Tags: python, file, text, text-processing

here I'm trying to merge text files and extract only message part of the files into a separate file

```
import os
import re
message_data=[]
path=r'C:\Users\Multiple Text files/'
filenames=['2019-01-01.text','2019-01-02.text','2019-01-03.text','2019-01-04.text','2019-01- 
          05.text','2019-01-06.text','2019-01-07.text']

#inside each file there is a message and I'm trying to extract that particular message only

with open(os.path.join(path,filenames),encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        m=re.findall('.*?Message:.*',line)
        for line in m:
            message_data.append(line)
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `sentiment-analysis`, or `nlp`- kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what it is that won't work (error or it just doesn't give output) but you can try to open the text files separately in a for-loop and see if you can find and extract the message. Separate blocks of code generally work best for me when trying to see why things won't work.